# Pulling in data from two APIs and want to match them up

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a side project around sports and sports betting. I am pulling in data from two different APIs, one for the schedule and one for the odds. I want to render cards for each game that include the odds on it. I want to filter through my array of games, mlbodds, and find the game from the array, dailyschedule, that matches the home team's name, then render those odds. Any help with my code, or any suggestions for a better way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

````
          {this.props.dailyschedule
            .filter((game) => game.status.short !== "CANC")
            .filter((game) => game.status.short !== "POST")
            .map((dailyScheduledGame) => {
              return (
                <Card key={dailyScheduledGame.id}>
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardHeader>
                      <strong>
                        {dailyScheduledGame.teams.away.name} at{" "}
                        {dailyScheduledGame.teams.home.name}
                      </strong>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardSubtitle>
                      <strong>
                        {this.props.mlbodds.filter((game) => game.home_team.replace(
                            /\s+/g,
                            ""
                          ) ===
                          dailyScheduledGame.teams.away.name.replace(
                            /\s+/g,
                            ""
                          )) ? this.props.mlbodds.sites[0].odds.h2h[0]:null}
                      </strong>
                    </CardSubtitle>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              );
            })}
        </CardColumns>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by applying condition of if statment

```
  {this.props.dailyschedule
                .map((dailyScheduledGame) => {
    if(dailyScheduledGame.status.short !== "CANC" && dailyScheduledGame.status.short !== "POST"){
    return(
            <div></div>
          )
    }

}
```

or

```
 {this.props.dailyschedule
        .filter((game) => game.status.short !== "CANC" && game.status.short !== "POST")
        .map((dailyScheduledGame) => {
          return (
)
```